# If $f(x) = x-5$ and $g(x) = x^2 -5$, what is $u(x)$ if $(u \circ f)(x) = g(x)$?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

> Let $f(x) = x-5$, $g(x) = x^2 -5$. Find $u(x)$ if $(u \circ f)(x) = g(x)$.

I know how to do it we have $(f \circ u) (x)$, but only because $f(x)$ was defined.  But here $u(x)$ is not defined.  Is there any way I can reverse it to get $u(x)$ alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** We are told that $u(x-5)=x^2-5$.  Let $t=x-5$. Now express $x^2-5$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: thanks that solved the problem.

Comment: can you please check my solution (at the bottom)? the teacher solved it, but i'm not sure if i copied it right. i just dont want to post another question.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$x^2-5=(x-5)(x+5)$$
$$(x+5)=(x-5)+10$$

Comment: are u using f inverse? my professor used an f inverse on the left and f on the right (this confused me) is that what you're doing?

Comment: No; my hint is essentially the same as André's. I was suggesting how you could write $x^2-5$ as a function of $x-5$.

Comment: ah ok thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out what my professor did now . . .

> $(u \circ f)(x) = g(x)$
>
> $(u \circ f)(f^{-1} (x)) = g( f^{-1}(x)) $
>
> $\big((u \circ f) \circ f^{-1}\big)(x) = (g \circ f^{-1})(x) $
>
> $\big(u \circ (f \circ f^{-1})\big)(x) = (g \circ f^{-1})(x) $
>
> $u(x) = g(f^{-1}(x))$
>
> $u(x) = g(x+5)$

I think this is right.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is essentially correct. There should be a line after the first that says $(u\circ f)(f^{-1}(x))=g(f^{-1}(x))$. Then the rest follows, and is fine except for some missing parentheses. The only downside to this approach is that it is very manipulational, and perhaps gives a little less concrete knowledge of what is going on.